# Single Big SQL Server lookup table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a snowflake-style schema, so lots of different lookup tables, like Language, Countries, States, Status, etc.  All these lookup table have almost identical structures: Two columns, Code and Decode. My project manager would like all of these different tables to be one BIG table, so I would need another column, say CodeCategory, and my primary key columns for this big table would be CodeCategory and Code.   The problem is that for any of the tables that have the actual code (say Language Code), I cannot establish a foreign key relationship into this big decode table, as the CodeCategory would not be in the fact table, just the code. And codes by themselves will not be unique (they will be within a CodeCategory), so I cannot make an FK from just the fact table code field into the Big lookup table Code field.

So am I missing something, or is this impossible to do and still be able to do FKs in the related tables?  I wish I could do this: have a FK where one of the columns I was matching to in the lookup table would match to a string constant. Like this (I know this is impossible but it gives you an idea what I want to do):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_User_AppCodes] 
FOREIGN KEY('Language', [LanguageCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AppCodes] ([AppCodeCategory], [AppCode])
```

The above does not work, but if it did I would have the FK I need. Where I have the string 'Language', is there any way in T-SQL to substitute the table name from code instead?

I absolutely need the FKs so, if nothing like this is possible, then I will have to stick with my may little lookup tables. any assistance would be appreciated.

Brian

Comment: a.k.a. the "One True Lookup Table", a well-known *anti-* pattern. Unless you're using some weird variant of SQL Server where you have to pay for each table, the sanity of simple foreign keys and simpler queries usually more than outweighs any perceived redundancy or inefficiency.

Comment: See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) and look at point #1 - that's exactly what your PM is proposing - and it should be **avoided** !

Comment: Your primary key will have to be a generated key value and you will have to create a composite unique key/constraint around the Code, CodeCategory or business key.  Like you mentioned you can't have a composite key relationship without some additional layer enforcing the logic.  In short its probably not a great idea to do this, though you do see it implemented in other database engines like Intersystems Cache

Comment: Thanks to all for comments, which I agree with, and appreciate the ammo you have given me.  Thanks marc_s, that was a great link. It is good to have your main concepts confirmed by other experts, especially those who are better than me. Thanks again.

Comment: Why is your project manager attempting to dictate system design details in the first place? Especially details that will significantly impact the performance and design of the application and **everything** that will touch its data?

Answer (score 4):

It is not impossible to accomplish this, but it is impossible to accomplish this *and* not hurt the system on several levels.

While a single lookup table (as has been pointed out already) is a truly horrible idea, I will say that this pattern does not require a single field PK or that it be auto-generated. It requires a composite PK comprised of `([AppCodeCategory], [AppCode])` and then **BOTH** fields need to be present in the fact table that would have a composite FK of both fields back to the PK. Again, this is not an endorsement of this particular end-goal, just a technical note that it is possible to have composite PKs and FKs in other, more appropriate scenarios.

The main problem with this type of approach to constants is that each constant is truly its own thing: Languages, Countries, States, Statii, etc are all completely separate entities. While the *structure* of them in the database is the same (as of today), the data within that structure does not represent the same things. You would be locked into a model that either disallows from adding additional lookup fields later (such as ISO codes for Language and Country but not the others, or something related to States that is not applicable to the others), or would require adding NULLable fields with no way to know which Category/ies they applied to (have fun debugging issues related to that and/or explaining to the new person -- who has been there for 2 days and is tasked with writing a new report -- that the 3 digit ISO Country Code does not apply to the "Deleted" status).

This approach also requires that you maintain an arbitrary "Category" field in all related tables. And that is *per lookup*. So if you have `CountryCode`, `LanguageCode`, and `StateCode` in the fact table, each of those FKs gets a matching CategoryID field, so now that is 6 fields instead of 3. Even if you were able to use `TINYINT` for CategoryID, if your fact table has even 200 million rows, then those three extra 1 byte fields now take up 600 MB, which adversely affects performance. And let's not forget that backups will take longer and take up more space, but disk is cheap, right? Oh, and if backups take longer, then restores also take longer, right? Oh, but the table has closer to 1 billion rows? Even better ;-).

While this approach *looks* maybe "cleaner" or "easier" now, it is actually more costly in the long run, especially in terms of wasted developer time, as you (and/or others) in the future try to work around issues related to this poor design choice.

Has anyone even asked your project manager what the intended benefit of this is? It is a reasonable question if you are going to spend some amount of hours making changes to the system that there be a stated benefit for that time spent. It certainly does not make interacting with the data any easier, and in fact will make it harder, especially if you choose a string for the "Category" instead of a `TINYINT` or maybe `SMALLINT`.

If your PM still presses for this change, then it should be required, as part of that project, to also change any `enum`s in the app code accordingly so that they match what is in the database. Since the database is having its values munged together, you can accomplish that in C# (assuming your app code is in C#, if not then translate to whatever is appropriate) by setting the `enum` values explicitly with a pattern of the first X digits are the "category" and the remaining Y digits are the "value". For example:

Assume the "Country" category == 1 and the "Language" catagory == 2, you could do:

```cs
enum AppCodes
{
  // Countries
  United States  = 1000001,
  Canada         = 1000002,
  Somewhere Else = 1000003,

  // Languages
  EnglishUS = 2000001,
  EnglishUK = 2000002,
  French    = 2000003
};
```

Absurd? Completely. But also analogous to the request of merging all lookup tables into a single table. What's good for the goose is good for the gander, right?

Comment: Thanks, Many good points, I hope you don't mind if I use them.  As architect and designer as well as developer, I agree about PMs doing their job and sticking to IT! Many thanks.

Comment: @user3772397 No problem. I updated with a little more at the end that _might_ help put things into perspective for the PM.

Comment: Your answer is so much better than mine I deleted mine.

Comment: @HLGEM Thanks for that compliment :). I have made a few edits to add clarification.

Comment: @ srutzky: Thanks for the addition! They make sense, are relevant to what I am doing, and help me to convince less IT-oriented people with input in to the decision.

Answer (score 0):

Is this being suggested so you can minimise the number of admin screens you need for CRUD operations on your standing data? I've been here before and decided it was better/safer/easier to build a generic screen which used metadata to decide what table to extract from/write to. It was a bit more work to build but kept the database schema 'correct'.

All the standing data tables had the same basic structure, they were mainly for dropdown population with occasional additional fields for business rule purposes.